# About letter f (float type) in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C/C++ programming, and i don't know why they put the letter 'f' in the end of a number when assign, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    float my_float = 2.34f;
    double my_double = 2.34;
}
```

I search for a while and i think that if i don't put this letter 'f', the variable my_float will be a double. am I right?
I find some way to find how memory use by a variable/ or type of it (in this case this is my_float) but i don't get it, someone can help me?

Comment: 2.34 = double
2.34f = float

They have different sizes in memory (and therefore accuracy)

Comment: They are called "literals" - here's the reference for C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals

Comment: OK, I got it, Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case they don't need to.

`2.34f` is a *literal* of type `float` (i.e. the other way round than you think judging by your question). Compare `2.34` which is a literal of type `double`.

In more detail, if you had written `float my_float = 2.34;` then the compiler would have performed the conversion for you implicitly.

Occasionally you *do* need to specify the literal explicitly. In C++, for example, consider

```
void foo(const double&){
    // reformat hard disk
}

void foo(const float&){
    // pay me a bonus
}

int main()
{
    foo(2.34f);
}
```

Here, we are forcing the appropriate overload of `foo` to be called.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: for a *numerical literal with a decimal point*, a suffix of `f` or `F` will tell the compiler your numerical literal should be taken as a `float` number, instead of as a `double`; it will be taken as a `long double` if the suffix is `l` or `L`.  In most systems *floats* have half the size in memory bytes, and therefore much less precision, than a *double* number.

This suffix comes from the good old C (although I don't know if it was used before in earlier languages).  I recommend you to have a look at the best book about C, **The C Programming Language**, by *Kernighan and Ritchie*.  In particular, from this book:

[image: Image from 'The C Programming Language, 2nd. Ed., Kernighan & Ritchie]

Comment: And do the example exercises at the end of each chapter.